# TTTAttributedLabel links are being styled but not clickable

Tags: ios, swift, hyperlink, tttattributedlabel

I've been looking into a solution to getting clickable links working. I can get this working when using UITextView + NSAttributedString but it just doesn't autolayout properly when it's a UITableViewCell.

Now I've added the TTTAttributedLabel to my project and it styles the views just perfectly. The links also turn blue and are underlined.

However clicking them does nothing. I did implement TTTAttributedLabelDelegate on my controller, made the label in the storyboard implement MyLabel (Which just extends TTTAttributedLabel and has the delegate options since I want them to fire inside the same function). For now I've set the controller to be the delegate I was thinking it might not work pointing to itself.

But none of these functions get fired, I got breakpoints and logs in it.

I Implemented didSelectLinkWithUrl and didLongPressLinkWithUrl.

```
 func attributedLabel(label: TTTAttributedLabel!, didSelectLinkWithURL url: NSURL!) {
        Debug.log("link clicked")
    }
    func attributedLabel(label: TTTAttributedLabel!, didLongPressLinkWithURL url: NSURL!, atPoint point: CGPoint) {
        Debug.log("link long clicked")
    }
```

Outlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var content: MyLabel!
```

MyLabel

import UIKit
import TTTAttributedLabel

```
class MyLabel : TTTAttributedLabel, TTTAttributedLabelDelegate {

override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    if (self.delegate == nil) {
        self.delegate = self
    }
    self.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue
    self.userInteractionEnabled = true
}

func attributedLabel(label: TTTAttributedLabel!, didSelectLinkWithURL url: NSURL!) {
    Debug.log("link clicked")
}
func attributedLabel(label: TTTAttributedLabel!, didLongPressLinkWithURL url: NSURL!, atPoint point: CGPoint) {
    Debug.log("link long clicked")
}
```

Anyone know what I could be missing?

**Update**

I found out that just pasting in an url f/e http://example.com becomes active and is actually clickable and the didSelectLinkWithUrl becomes clickable, allthough I need an attributed string and it's based on a HTML String.

Comment: Swift 3/4: `NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[The implementation of `setAttributedText:`](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel/blob/13d2d877707032dc4d4b888bb3832bac822bf9b0/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel.m#L465) doesn't update the `linkModels` array, while [the implementation of `setText:`](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel/blob/13d2d877707032dc4d4b888bb3832bac822bf9b0/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel.m#L1129) does. I believe this is what causes your issue.

To resolve, set the label's `text` property instead of the `attributedText` property.

[The docs](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel/) also include this warning:

> `TTTAttributedLabel` can display both plain and attributed text: just pass an `NSString` or `NSAttributedString` to the `setText:` setter. **Never assign to the `attributedText` property.**

The docs also show this example usage:

```
TTTAttributedLabel *attributedLabel = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Tom Bombadil"
                                                                attributes:@{
        (id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName : (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor,
        NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16],
        NSKernAttributeName : [NSNull null],
        (id)kTTTBackgroundFillColorAttributeName : (id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor
}];

// The attributed string is directly set, without inheriting any other text
// properties of the label.
attributedLabel.text = attString;
```

Comment: @MathijsSegers I added some more details about why this behavior occurs - but basically, just set your attributed string to the `text` property.

Comment: @MathijsSegers can u please show ur pice of swift code, I really cant get it to work. It says:  Cannot assign value of type 'NSAttributedString' to type 'String?'

Comment: @hugocarlmartin, instead of `label.text = attrbText`, use `label.setText(attrbText)`.

Answer (score 2):

Aaron Brager is correct!
I used to have the same problem, but I got it fixed in Swift by replacing the line:

```
label.attributedText = attributedString
```

with the line:

```
label.setText(attributedString)
```

This is accepted by the compiler because the setText method accepts AnyObject.
I also increased the font of the attributed string of the link so it captures my tap and it is working now!
I used this for the truncation link, this is the whole part:

```
label.lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingHead
label.attributedTruncationToken = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "... Show more", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.cueCyan(), NSLinkAttributeName: readMoreLink, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.formFont(.Light, size: fontSize+24)!])
label.userInteractionEnabled = true
label.delegate = self
```

Comment: Can you include an example of the readMoreLink?